# TCPDF ERROR on pdf generator launched by cron

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I have a problem with a PDF generator script (using html2pdf lib). **The script works perfectly when launched manually but returns this error when launched as a cron task**.

***TCPDF ERROR:** Unable to create output file: /0000/images/upload/demonstration/factures/2016-05-demonstration.pdf*

Here's the part of the script involved in the creation.

```
require('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
        try
            {
            $pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
            $pdf->writeHTML($content);
            ob_end_clean();
            $pdf->Output(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/0000/images/upload/'.$data["id_client"].'/factures/'.$fichier.'.pdf', 'F');
            }
        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            die($e);
            }
```

I tried many solutions suggested in other threads but nothing worked so far. The files and directories have permissions 777 and I'm using the right absolute path (the fact that it works manually proves it).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not available when running PHP via the command line since DOCUMENT_ROOT is an Apache variable set in the VHost config.  You can see in the error message that the variable is clearly empty and it's trying to write to a directory called "0000" in the root of your operating system.

You have to set the document root some other way when running via the CLI like:

1. By setting an environment variable
2. Creating a configuration file specifically for the CLI job.
3. Setting the DOCUMENT_ROOT index directly in PHP (eg: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/path/to/document/root';)

   4. Hard coding the path

**STEP 1**

Figure out what the document root actually is. You can do it this way:

```
die(var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

Make sure to run the above temp code via your web browser (not by cron) and it will tell you what your document root is.

**STEP 2**

Pick one of the options I provided above.

Let's say you choose option 4 (Hard coding).  Replace $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in your code with whatever path you got in step 1 above. It will now work both via a browser and via cron.

IMPORTANT NOTE: The document root changes between servers so if you are going to next deploy your code to another server you have to know what the document root is on that specific server.

Comment: thanks for the explanation !
So, I tried different options : 

Relative path : $pdf->Output('../images/upload/'.$data["id_client"].'/factures/'.$fichier.'.pdf', 'F');

Works fine manually but doesn't seem to be working on Cron.

Comment: Absolte path (hard code) : $pdf->Output('http://'.$data["domaine"].'/images/upload/'.$data["id_client"].'/factures/'.$fichier.'.pdf', 'F');

Warning: fopen(http://www.domain.fr/images/upload/demonstration/factures/2016-05-demonstration.pdf): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/yatacrea/www/0000/scripts/html2pdf/_tcpdf_5.0.002/tcpdf.php on line 6168
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: http://www.domain.fr/images/upload/demonstration/factures/2016-05-demonstration.pdf

Comment: None of the things you tried will work. The working directory is different under Apache than cron so a relative path won't work. In your next attemp you are trying to write to a http stream which also won't work.  Let me update my answer with more precise info.